# How do I clear all the queues on a server with F#?

Tags: f#, msmq

I've been searching all over for an easy way to clear out all of the queues in MSMQ for a given server. I don't need to create or delete queues, simply clear out any messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a hard time finding this answer so decided to post what I found. There's probably some variations on this as far as creating scripts vs fsi but this was my solution.

Create a script with this in it:

```
open System
open System.Messaging

let purgeQueue (server :string) =
    let qs = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine server
    for q in qs do
        printfn "%O" q.QueueName
        q.Purge()
```

Launch fsi and #r System.Messaging.dll. Then load this script in and run call purgeQueue on the server you want. My case I passed localhost since I was on the box.

Answer (score 4):

@Joshua -- I added a few extra bits to your code, just for the heck of it. This automatically references `System.Messaging.dll` and allows you to toggle whether to clear both public and private queues or just public queues.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.Messaging.dll"
#endif

open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Messaging

//
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Queue =
    //
    let purgeByMachine includePrivateQueues (machineName : string) =
        let queues =
            let publicQueues = MessageQueue.GetPublicQueuesByMachine machineName
            if includePrivateQueues then
                let privateQueues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine machineName
                Array.append publicQueues privateQueues
            else
                publicQueues

        queues
        |> Array.iter (fun queue ->
            sprintf "Purging queue: %s" queue.QueueName
            |> Trace.WriteLine

            queue.Purge ())
```